# Only recurse subfolder x numbers of levels using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

The PowerShell script below will list out all shared folders (excluding hidden shared folders), then list out all sub-folders and finally get the ACL information of each of them and export to a CSV file.

However, I'm trying to set the limit of the sub-folder it can drill into. For example, if I set it to 3, the script will get the ACL information of first three sub-folders. How can I do this?

Input:

```
path=\\server\sharefolder0\subfolder01\subfolder02
path=\\server\sharefolder1\subfolder11\subfolder12\subfolder13\subfolder14
path=\\server\sharefolder2
```

Expected result:

```
path=\\server\sharefolder0
path=\\server\sharefolder0\subfolder01
path=\\server\sharefolder0\subfolder01\subfolder02
path=\\server\sharefolder1
path=\\server\sharefolder1\subfolder11
path=\\server\sharefolder1\subfolder11\subfolder12
path=\\server\sharefolder2
```

This is the code:

```
$getSRVlist = Get-Content .\server.txt
$outputDirPath=".\DirPathList.txt"
$outputACLInfo=".\ACLInfo.CSV"
$header="FolderPath,IdentityReference,Rights"
Del $outputACLInfo
add-content -value $header -path $outputACLInfo
foreach ($readSRVlist in $getSRVlist)
{
   foreach ($readShareInfoList in $getShareInfoList=Get-WmiObject Win32_Share
   -computerName $readSRVlist | Where {$_.name -notlike "*$"} | %{$_.Name})
   {
      foreach ($readDirPathList in
      $getDirPathList=get-childitem \\$readSRVlist\$readShareInfoList -recurse
      | where {$_.PSIsContainer})# | %{$_.fullname})
      {
         $getACLList=get-ACL $readDirPathList.fullname | ForEach-Object
         {$_.Access}
         foreach ($readACLList in $getACLList)
         {
            $a = $readDirPathList.fullname + "," +
            $readACLList.IdentityReference + "," +  $readACLList.FileSystemRights
            add-content -value $a -path $outputACLInfo
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recursion is your friend. Try this:

```
$maxDepth = 3

function TraverseFolders($folder, $remainingDepth) {
  Get-ChildItem $folder | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($remainingDepth -gt 1) {
      TraverseFolders $_.FullName ($remainingDepth - 1)
    }
  }
}

TraverseFolders "C:\BASE\PATH" $maxDepth
```

**Edit:** Now I see what you mean. For checking the first three parent folders of a given path try this:

```
$server   = "\\server\"
$path = ($args[0] -replace [regex]::escape($server), "").Split("\\")[0..2]
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $path.Length; $i++) {
  Get-ACL ($server + [string]::join("\", $path[0..$i])
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Ansgar.
output seems to be not what i expected. maybe i didnt stated it clearly. when a path passed to the script, it will only get the folder's ACL info up to first 3 level. example,

<pre>
path=\\server\sharefolder0
</pre>

Comment: example,path=\\server\sharefolder0 passed to the script, it will get the folder'ACL up to first 3 level 

\\server\sharefolder0\folder00
\\server\sharefolder0\folder01\folder11
\\server\sharefolder1\folder00\folder01
\\server\sharefolder1\folder01\folder11
\\server\sharefolder2\folder00
\\server\sharefolder2\folder01\folder11

Comment: hmm ... getting error msg below. i'm trying to play around with it but not luck. not sure what i missed.

Missing 'in' after variable in foreach loop.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\ps\Get-FolderPermission\test.ps1:3 char:13
+ foreach ($i  <<<< = 0; $i -lt $path.Length) {
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (InToken:TokenId) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingInInForeach

Comment: My bad. When updating my answer I mistakenly wrote `foreach` instead of `for`. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

In newer version of powershell one can use `-DEPTH` parameter,
One liner can help-

```
 get-childitem -path \\server\folder -Depth 2 -Directory | Select-object -Property Name, Fullname
```

It will search for 2 nested folders and will provide folder name and full path of that particular folder. Tested in version- **PSVersion                      5.1.17134.858**